# is there a regular expression to find same sentence in MS Word (repeated Sentence)

Tags: ms-word

I need to search similar sentence from the file. can i do it? the difference will bee just a punctuation 
E.g
Sentence1: Vérifier les courroies d’entraînement

Sentence2: Vérifier les courroies d’entraînement:

Comment: No, I don't think that they is a way to do it inside word. I think the best way to do it is to extract the whole text and check with an external application

Answer (score 0):

```
using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

 word.ApplicationClass worddapp;
 word.Document worddoc;
```

// This is the Code to Get Two Equal Sentences in Word Document

```
 for(int i=1;i<=worddoc.Sentences.Count;i++)
  {
    for(int j=1;j<=worddoc.Sentences.Count;j++)
     {
       if(i!=j)
        if(worddoc.Sentences[i].Text.Trim().Equals(worddoc.Sentences[j].Text.Trim()))
           MessageBox.Show("Both the Sentences are Equal");
      }
  }
```

Comment: `sentence 1` from OP question will not be recognised as a `Word sentence object` because there isn't any ending mark. Your code will not work correctly in this situation. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it would only work if it is a complete sentence.